# Collect content from dynamic key in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

I am using Gatsby and would like to access the following data in GraphQL. I have the following data structure (only showing 2 data).

```
{
  "data": {
    "allData": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "schedule": {
            "_01": [
              {
                "BoundText1": "05:35 - 06:23"
              },
              {
                "BoundText1": "06:23 - 08:29"
              },
              {
                "BoundText1": "08:29 - 23:40"
              },
              {
                "BoundText1": "05:35 - 20:12"
              },
              {
                "BoundText1": "20:12 - 23:40"
              },
              {
                "BoundText1": ""
              },
              {
                "BoundText1": "05:35 - 23:00"
              },
              {
                "BoundText1": "23:00 - 23:40"
              },
              {
                "BoundText1": ""
              }
            ],
            "_02": null,
            "_03": null,
            "_04": null,
            "_05": null,
            "_07": null,
            "_08": null,
            "_09": null
          }
        },
        {
          "schedule": {
            "_01": [
              {
                "BoundText1": "05:35 - 06:23"
              },
              {
                "BoundText1": "06:23 - 08:29"
              },
              {
                "BoundText1": "08:29 - 23:40"
              },
              {
                "BoundText1": "05:35 - 20:12"
              },
              {
                "BoundText1": "20:12 - 23:40"
              },
              {
                "BoundText1": ""
              },
              {
                "BoundText1": "05:35 - 23:00"
              },
              {
                "BoundText1": "23:00 - 23:40"
              },
              {
                "BoundText1": ""
              }
            ],
            "_02": null,
            "_03": null,
            "_04": null,
            "_05": null,
            "_07": null,
            "_08": null,
            "_09": null
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "extensions": {}
}
```

As seen, under `data.allData.nodes[].schedule` the key is totally dynamic and its generated by the server side (It's `_01` to `_09` currently but it is totally up to the server side. I'd like to access the list of `BoundText1` under each key.

I created the following query that let me query the value I want:

```
query MyQuery {
  allData: allData {
    nodes {
      schedule {
        _01 {
          BoundText1
        }
        _02 {
          BoundText1
        }
        _03 {
          BoundText1
        }
        _04 {
          BoundText1
        }
        _05 {
          BoundText1
        }
        _07 {
          BoundText1
        }
        _08 {
          BoundText1
        }
        _09 {
          BoundText1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However I'm afraid that in the future if there are some new key is added from the server side (e.g. `_88`), I would miss the new data. Therefore I would like to know if there are some possible way that I can grab `BoundText1` under all keys?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `"nodes": [` - it's an array ... schedule elements should be array entries, too ... bad types/structure?

Comment: Oh yeah my bad, it is an array of object. And in that object, schedule is one of the object which include the all the numbers as key and a list of object as values.

Comment: ask API devs for reasons of this [strange/hackish/non-standard] decision and solution?

Comment: I am not sure if this is non standard or I lack the knowledge of getting this. I am not sure. Therefore I come over and ask for guidance.

Comment: again, ask your API devs

Comment: I would like to say that this is a public API and sadly I have no control of it at all

Comment: url? public API has support and devs/authors, too

Comment: Actually I make multiple API calls and feed the data into GraphQL, which is used by Gatsby for generating webpages, here are the API calls

1. https://search.kmb.hk/KMBWebSite/Function/FunctionRequest.ashx?action=getschedule&route=101&bound=1 , this one has ```09```, but

2. https://search.kmb.hk/KMBWebSite/Function/FunctionRequest.ashx?action=getschedule&route=1&bound=1 has only ```01```

Comment: feed it proper graphql way, convert in the middle

Comment: @xadm I totally agree that would do. However I am just the middleman, not the frontend (Gatsby can create static pages and also create static json file, I am using Gatsby to create static json file for frontend to consume). The frontend is already created so for minimal changes modification not changing the json content is preferred. However I can still talk to the frontend guy and make the changes.

Answer (score 0):

As [xadm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6124657/xadm) mentioned, the data source is not GraphQL friendly. I removed the object key and convert the object into list before feeding into GraphQL.

Now everything works as expected. Seems getting all keys would not be very feasible.